# Is there an example of a, non-Hausdorff, topological vector space which has bounded subspaces

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space which is not Hausdorff.

Is it true that every non-trivial subspace $M$ of $E$ is necessarily unbounded?

Or, does there exist, non-Hausdorff, topological vector spaces containing non-trivial bounded subspaces? If any, what would be a counterexample?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the semi-norm $$\|(x,y) \| := |x|$$ and the subspace $$Y:= \{(0,y) : y \in \mathbb{R} \}, $$ then $( \mathbb{R}^2, \| \cdot \|)$ is a non-Hausdorff TVS with bounded subspace $Y$.

Comment: Let $\tau$ the topology of $E$. In general,
$$\bigcap_{U\in\tau,U\ni 0}\overline{U}$$
is a bounded subspace and is non-trivial iff $E$ is non-Hausdorff

Comment: @S. Dewar:  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your examples all make sense - so why does Rudin say that every topological vector space is Hausdorff?

Comment: @rem Rudin makes the extra assumption that the space also be $T_1$ i.e. points are closed sets. In this case all TVS are Hausdorff. With the more general definition (only assuming that scalar multiplication and addition are continuous) this is not a given, as seen by my example

Comment: @VeridianDynamics that seems like it should be another answer, not a comment.