# Does there exists a non-Hausdorff topological vector space with a proper convex open subset?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Wikipedia's page on the Hahn-Banach theorem [mentions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Applications) a technique that converts a non-Hausdorff topological vector space $X$ into a (Hausdorff) locally convex one: apply the weak topology (induced by $X^*$).  However, the argument assumes that $X$ contains a proper, convex, open set.

The standard example of a non-Hausdorff topological vector space is $\mathrm{Spec}{(\mathbb{R}[\vec{x}])}$ with the Zariski topology.  This does not contain a proper open *convex* subset.

**What is an example of a non-Hausdorff topological vector space to which this technique applies?**

Comment: The Zariski topology does not make $\mathbb{R}^n$ a topological vector space.  Addition is not continuous.

Comment: In fact, every non-Hausdorff topological vector space has the form of the example in your answer: it is a product of a Hausdorff topological vector space with an indiscrete vector space.

Comment: @EricWofsey: (#1) Oops.  I should have known better --- this sort of thing is *why* we have schemes.  My algebraic geometry is getting rusty, I guess.  Thanks.

Comment: @EricWofsey: (#2) That sounds like it would make an interesting answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is!  Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the indiscrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and consider $X=\mathbb{R}\times(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{T})$.  This is a topological vector space (exercise); and $(-1,1)\times\mathbb{R}$ is an example of a proper convex open subset.

In fact one can show more:

1. $X$ has a topology induced by the seminorm $\|(x,y)\|=|x|$.
2. $X$ is locally convex (even without the "weak topology trick").
3. $X^*\cong\mathbb{R}^*\oplus0$; all continuous functionals on $X$ are constant on the second direct factor.

I leave these claims, as well as the construction of an infinite-dimensional example, to the interested reader.

Finally, a general remark: the Zariski topology is *much* more pathological than one needs to obtain non-Hausdorffness.  You should maybe consider re-reading [Stein and Seebach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology).

(This answer inspired by [Answer #330413: Is there an example of a, non-Hausdorff, topological vector space which has bounded subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2735432/330413).)